# is there a way to add a delay to a java program without using sleep?

Tags: java, timer

In my game i have some stats that i want to go down after a certain period of time but i cant use the sleep thing. Can someone give me an example of a better way of doing this?
I've seen videos on something called the swing timer but none of the videos are helping me much. I've also heard about the timer util however there seems to be almost no videos on that.

here's what I tried to do:

```
int hunger = 10;

 public void hungerDown(){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        hunger--;
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to setup your own timer, of sorts. You need to place some kind of "action" on a list/queue, which has a it e attached to it. The on each loop of your game loop, you'd need to check if any of the actions need to be run

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make a game? If so you should have a gameloop. This will keep track of timing, updates, and rendering.
Here is a good website to get you started.

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 1):

```
ScheduledExecutorService execService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

public void hungerDown() {
    scheduledThreadPool.schedule(new Runnable() {
        hunger --;
    }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has a mechanism [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) for this purpose. E.g.,

```
long delayMs = 1000;
new Timer().schedule(
    new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* your delayed logic */
        }
    },
    delayMs
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and call `ScheduledExecutorService.schedule(Callable<V> callable, long delay, TimeUnit unit)`. You can get an instance by using one the factory methods from `java.util.concurrent.Executors`.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to offer a code example right now but you may find a [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) useful.

Essentially - you could create a `DelayQueue` and post a delayed item into it. Then fire up a `Thread` that just waits for something to come out of the queue.